# list unprotected worksheets in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel workbook I have over 20 sheets. However, some have been password protected allowing users only access to particular cells where they can change the values. Some of the sheets are left unprotected. I have the following code to check if the sheet is unprotected.

```
Sub Check_if_Unprotected()
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
MsgBox "Protected"
Else
MsgBox "Not protected"
End If
End Sub
```

However, to run the above macro 20 plus times at the close of the day is laborious. I want macro to create a sheet called "unprotected" and populate the sheet with list of the unprotected sheets.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SO is not for requesting code, there are other websites for that. besides that, are the sames sheets always protected? If so wouldn't it just be easier to for example put a (P) at the end of the sheet name to define its protected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
Macro create a sheet and record all unprotected sheet name.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Range
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "Unprotected"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.ProtectContents = False And ws.Name <> "Unprotected" Then
        CNT = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Unprotected").Cells(CNT + 1, "A") = ws.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Perfect Sy Chen, appreciated.